# Is it redundant to say tremendous catastrophic consequences?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

According to [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/catastrophe), **catastrophe** means:

> a sudden event that causes **very great** trouble or destruction.

Since "catastrophe" already means an event with major consequences, is it **redundant** to use "tremendous" in the following sentence? I am trying to emphasize the scale of consequences.

> Overpopulation may have some **tremendous catastrophic consequences** in a not-too-distant future.

Actually, I am curious to know which one is a better sentence? The following or the above?

> Overpopulation may have some **catastrophic consequences** in a not-too-distant future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to emphasis the greatness of consequences.

Then I suggest you use this instead:

> *serious consequences*

If you had to use *catastrophic*, you could juse use

> *catastrophic consequences*

If you really had to emphasize *catastrophic*, you might add *truly*:

> *truly catastrophic consequences*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the phrase is redundant. They both mean something like "large and terrible." Of the two, "catastrophic" is the more informative, so I recommend using that on its own. Whatever subtle distinction is added by "tremendous" is not worth the added burden of reading it. In common usage, "tremendous" is also ambiguous: native speakers use it to describe things that are very bad AND very good.

It might seem silly to talk about the cognitive burden of one word. I do so because you should develop a habit of writing concisely in all your sentences. It's the accumulation of extra words that can become a burden. I read verbose essays by university students for a living.

Answer (score -2):

Since there's no comma between them, no. Were there a comma between them, maybe it'd be redundant. There not being a comma, though, means that they're not coordinate adjectives, so "tremendous" isn't modifying "consequences" along with "catastrophic" but instead is modifying "catastrophic consequences."

To be clear, the phrase "tremendous catastrophic consequences" means that the "catastrophic" consequences" were "tremendous," *not* that the "consequences" were "tremendous" and "catastrophic, which would arguably be redundant.

Since "tremendous" modifies "catastrophic consequences," it's not redundant because it's saying that in terms of "catastrophic consequences," which are already definitively "very great," these are "tremendous," a "tremendous" "very great," like "very, very great," which likewise isn't redundant. So, relatively speaking, as far as "catastrophic consequences" go with their definitive *"very great"*-ness, these were "tremendous," meaning much larger than the *"very great"*-ness of typical "catastrophic consequences."

In a nutshell, "tremendous catastrophic consequences," sans comma, essentially means the same thing as "tremendously catastrophic consequences," just rather than using the adverb case to modify the adjective "catastrophic" as being even much bigger than what "catastrophic" normally denotes, the adjective case is being used to modify the phrase "catastrophic consequences."

The lack of a comma between "tremendous" and "catastrophic" makes all the difference.

Comment: I have never heard of a catastrophe or anything catastrophic also needing to be described as "tremendous". That sounds an awful lot like language abuse.